# Is it possible to increase max scheduled time for azure notification hub?

Tags: azure, push-notification, azure-notificationhub

We use azure notification hub to send notifications to mobile devices. One of our business requirement is to be able to schedule notifications. As part of system refactoring we decided to get rid of our scheduler and use azure notification hub feature to schedule notification. According to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-send-push-notifications-scheduled) it's only possible to schedule notifications up to seven days in the future. So, is it some how possible to bypass this restriction? Also, it's not clear from documentation what'd happen if you set scheduled time more that 7 days from now.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately this restriction isn't quite as arbitrary as it seems. It's coming from an underlying system that Notification Hub uses to park those scheduled notifications that forces that limit, and there is no way to increase that limit.

So we aren't able to pass along any kind of increase to customers. If you scheduled for longer than that, I believe Notification Hubs would reject the request.